# The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit in weblogic 12.2

Tags: java, weblogic12c, atg-dynamo

I have upgraded from WebLogic 12.1.3 to WebLogic 12.2. Now my application some pages are breaking up and showing the below errors. I have used JSTL and DSP (Dynamo server page) Tags on my JSP page.

Kindly help me on resolving this issue.

Error from an implicit include in "prelude.jspf" at line 35:
The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Comment: any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical behavior (anti-pattern?) when upgrading the WLS version. It happens because new libraries that are referenced in compilation time add heavier final bytecode and cannot be bigger than 64kb for runtime.

The only solution/workaround is to split that JSP into two or more submodules.